# the system cannot find the file specified even though input is in same directory as java code

Tags: java

I am trying to run this code and I get error as the system cannot find the file specified. My file is in the same directory as the code. I am specifying the full path name also. So what is the problem?

```
public class StopWordsSol
    {

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // ask for the stop words file name and read in stop words
    System.out.print("Please type the stop words file name: ");
    String[] stopWords = readStopWords(keyboard.next());

    // ask for the text file and remove stop words
    System.out.print("Please type the text file name: ");
    removeStopWords(keyboard.next(), stopWords);

    }

    // read stop words from the file and return an array of stop words
    public static String[] readStopWords(String stopWordsFilename) 
    {
    String[] stopWords = null;

    try
        {
        Scanner stopWordsFile = new Scanner(new File(stopWordsFilename));
        int numStopWords = stopWordsFile.nextInt();
        stopWords = new String[numStopWords];
        for (int i = 0; i < numStopWords; i++)
            stopWords[i] = stopWordsFile.next();

        stopWordsFile.close();
        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
        }

    return stopWords;
    }



}
```

Comment: I bet you'll find this is `Scanner`, not file, related. Separate your `keyboard.next()` and `readStopWords(...)` and `removeStopWords(...)` calls and use the debugger to look at the actual filename you're asking for. Looking at things in your debugger is **the first** thing to do.

Comment: Your code gets compiled and placed in a different directory when it is ran. That is why having the file in the "src" folder throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite common problem: the base-directory of the program is usually **not** the same as the directory the source-code is stored in. Try the following lines:

```
Path cd = Paths.get("");
System.out.println("cd= " + cd.toAbsolutePath());
```

Which will print the working-directory of your program.